# Inline style shortens other divs width

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, flexbox

Trying to create an inline style box using [Foundation 6](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites.html) but the width of `product-detail` loss its full width. Why?

**HTML: See updated below**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-10 large-centered columns">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="image">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="product-detail">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{ display: inline-flex }
.product-detail{ left: 20px }
```

How to get `.image` and `.product-detail` in one line without the loss of the width?

Edit:

Apologies for not being 100% precise. `box` holds the `card` class from [bootstrap card](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/). So my exact html looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-10 large-centered columns">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="image">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="product-detail">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `.image` and `.product-detail` in one line by making their parent a flex container.

```
.box { display: flex: }
```

You can then control the width of each child with the `width`, `flex-basis` or `flex` properties.

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.1/foundation-flex.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="small-10 columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-10 columns">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="columns">
        <p class="product-detail">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
          publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns">
    There is two left over columns here unused
  </div>
</div>
```

This version of foundation is older because I wanted to use a CDN version that had the flex-grid in it. Turns out that by not specifying the size of column (on the second column for text) you are just saying to take up what ever space is left.  See: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-grid.html

*note*: when testing make sure you switch to full page view...remember the grid is responsive.

Comment: I wish not to use that column.